# Sending a URL via a SOAP request

Tags: c#, xml, soap, upnp, dlna

I'm communicating with a TV via SOAP requests in order to get it to play video urls. This all works nicely for simple urls, such as `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4` but as soon as arguments are added to the url `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4?fname=fred&lname=jones` the XML is malformed (the '&' symbol has a special meaning in XML).

My question is whether or not there is a method I can use to send the message so that the XML is valid and the TV is still able to decipher the url. An example message looks as follows:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> 
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" s:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">
    <s:Body> 
        <u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1\"> 
            <InstanceID>0</InstanceID> 
            <CurrentURI>http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4</CurrentURI> 
            <CurrentURIMetaData>NOT_IMPLEMENTED</CurrentURIMetaData> 
        </u:SetAVTransportURI> 
    </s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

I've already tried the following:

- Enclosing the url in <[!CDATA[]]> (this fails, as the TV just takes all the text from in the  tag)
- Encoding the url using url encoding (replacing special characters, such as '&' with %26. The TV thinks it's an invalid URL)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try using `&amp;` instead of `&`

```
http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4?fname=fred&amp;lname=jones
```

Comment: Thanks, we tried that but it fails to decode on the TV end

Comment: Looks like you have an advanced-primitive TV. How about shortening the url using a url shortener like bitly and pass that to the TV?

Comment: Nice idea, just gave it a shot, doesn't work with any sort of link. It doesn't seem to like the redirects :/

Comment: It looks like the TV only wants the link to a video file. Why do you want to pass query string parameters along with the link to the mp4 file? My guess the TV will connect to internet, download the video file and play it. It has no purpose of having the query string parameters.

Comment: You would probably be better of by contacting the support team of the TV manufacturer.